# spring transaction timeout configurable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a transactional method which has a fixed timeout. Is there a way to make a transaction timeout configurable through i.e. an `application.yml`?

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout = TIMEOUT)
public String doStuff(String id) throws Exception {
    service.doSomeStuff
}
```

Comment: timeout = TIMEOUT, here TIMEOUT is passed as a configuration and is a variable, you may use @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout = 10), what else do you need?

Comment: @ Anurag Sharma     Because he wants to to set the timeout programatically , which the value is read from a property file. However java annotation only allow the attribute to be a constant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As we cannot assign variable value to Java annotation attribute , to programmatically set `@Transactional` 's `timeout` , your best bet is to override `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager#determineTimeout()`.

Suppose you are using `JpaTransactionManager`, the new manager looks like the code below. It allows to set timeout per transaction. We can use `TransactionDefinition` 's name to identify a transaction ,which in case of Spring declarative transaction ,the default name is in the format of `FullyQualifiedClassName.MethodName`.

```
public class FooTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {
    
    private Map<String, Integer> txTimeout = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public <T> void configureTxTimeout(Class<T> clazz, String methodName, Integer timeoutSecond) {
        txTimeout.put(clazz.getName() + "." + methodName, timeoutSecond);
    }

    //The timeout set by `configureTxTimeout` will have higher priority than the one set in @Transactional
    @Override
    protected int determineTimeout(TransactionDefinition definition) {;
        if (txTimeout.containsKey(definition.getName())) {
            return txTimeout.get(definition.getName());
        } else {
            return super.determineTimeout(definition);
        }
    }   
}
```

Then configure the `PlatformTransactionManager`:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    final FooTransactionManager transactionManager = new FooTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    transactionManager.configureTxTimeout(Foo.class, "doStuff", 10);
    transactionManager.configureTxTimeout(Bar.class, "doStuff", 20);
    transactionManager.configureTxTimeout(Bar.class, "doMoreStuff", 30);
    //blablabla
    
    return transactionManager;
}
```

The codes above is just for demonstration purpose . In reality , you can use `@Value` to read the value from an external properties (e.g `application.yml`) during the configuration.

---

Update On 25-Jun-2020 :

- It will be supported out of the box in the coming 5.3 (See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25052))