# Spring Transaction TimeOut Value Programmatically

Tags: java, spring, transactions, timeout

I want to give transaction time out value generic. This value should be given parametric.

This code block is work but not parametric.

```
@Transactional(timeout=10)
@Override
public List<EntityModel> search(EntityModel model) {
    List list = new ArrayList<EntityModel>();
    try {
        Criteria criteria = createCriteria(model);
        list = criteria.list();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return list;
}
```

This is parametric but is not work. I have given timeout value from database programmatically. I took advantage of this page http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2012/08/spring-query-timeout-or-transaction.html

```
@Transactional
@Override
public List<EntityModel> search(EntityModel model) {
    List list = new ArrayList<EntityModel>();
    try {
        Criteria criteria = createCriteria(model);

        EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(info.getDataSource());
         transactionManager.setDefaultTimeout(PropertyUtil.getTimeoutMiliseconds());            
         list = criteria.list();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151182/spring-transaction-timeout-configurable

Comment: I can set applicationContext.xml file as <!-- Transaction Manager -->
 <bean id="TM" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="EMF" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiEntityDataSource" />
    <property name="defaultTimeout" value="2" />
    
 </bean>

Comment: You should follow this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158592/1631731